# Is using "Lord" in a nickname or the sort haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, asma-ul-husna

What is the ruling of using the word lord in a nickname or anything of the sort?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by the word "Lord" the same meaning of the Arabic word "رب" then you might like to know that the Holy Quran has used this word to describe human beings, not just Allah Himself. Here are two Ayas from Surat Yousuf:

> 42
>   وَقَالَ لِلَّذِي ظَنَّ أَنَّهُ نَاجٍ مِّنْهُمَا اذْكُرْنِي عِندَ رَبِّكَ فَأَنسَاهُ الشَّيْطَانُ ذِكْرَ رَبِّهِ فَلَبِثَ فِي السِّجْنِ بِضْعَ سِنِينَ

Translation:

> 42. And he said to the one whom he knew to be saved: "Mention me to your lord (i.e. your king, so as to get me out of the prison)." But Shaitan (Satan) made him forget to mention it to his Lord [or Satan made [(Yusuf (Joseph)] to forget the remembrance of his Lord (Allah) as to ask for His Help, instead of others]. So [Yusuf (Joseph)] stayed in prison a few (more) years.

and the other Aya:

> 50
>   وَقَالَ الْمَلِكُ ائْتُونِي بِهِ فَلَمَّا جَاءَهُ الرَّسُولُ قَالَ ارْجِعْ إِلَى رَبِّكَ فَاسْأَلْهُ مَا بَالُ النِّسْوَةِ الَّلاتِي قَطَّعْنَ أَيْدِيَهُنَّ إِنَّ رَبِّي بِكَيْدِهِنَّ عَلِيمٌ

Translation:

> 50. And the king said: "Bring him to me." But when the messenger came to him, [Yusuf (Joseph)] said: "Return to your lord and ask him, 'What happened to the women who cut their hands? Surely, my Lord (Allah) is Well-Aware of their plot.'"

So I see no harm in using the word since the Quran uses the word to refer to Allah as well as human kings, masters, etc.
Not to mention, that we in Arabic say the word "Lord" in situations like:
رب الأسرة  meaning `Family Lord` which is essentially the man of the family (the father, the guardian, etc).